# Arrow keys and | less

Tags: command-line, directory, less

I'm new to Ubuntu and I was playing around in the terminal. Not sure what I stumbled into with two things:

I'm in /bin and when I type the command

```
dir | less
```

it displays the content in two alphabetical columns. I can use the up and down arrows to navigate. It makes sense. But when I press the right arrow it shows me only one column clearly not in alphabetical format, pressing the right key once more takes me to a blank terminal where I can "log file:"

1. What's the purpose of the second screen with the single column?
2. What is the third screen with "log file:" and how do you use it?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't hit the `s` key? That would be the equivalent of invoking `less` with the `-o` option (*"Causes  less to copy its input to the named file as it is being viewed."*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not exactly second and third screen. When you press the right arrow `less` scrolls to the right and what you see probably is an ugly transformed part of the output of the `dir` command. When you press the right arrow once again, there is nothing more to show on the right so you see blank screen.

The following is a part of [`man less`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/less.1.html)

> `ESC-)` or `RIGHTARROW` - Scroll horizontally right N characters,
> default half the screen width (see the `-#` option). If a number N is
> specified, it becomes the default for future RIGHTARROW and LEFTARROW
> commands. While the text is scrolled, it acts as though the -S option
> (chop lines) were in effect.
>
> `ESC-(` or `LEFTARROW` - Scroll horizontally left N characters, default
> half the screen width (see the `-#` option). If a number N is specified,
> it becomes the default for future RIGHTARROW and LEFTARROW commands.
>
> `ESC-}` or `^RIGHTARROW` - Scroll horizontally right to show the end of
> the longest displayed line.
>
> `ESC-{` or `^LEFTARROW` - Scroll horizontally left back to the first
> column.
>
> `-#` or `--shift` option - Specifies the default number of positions to
> scroll horizontally in the RIGHTARROW and LEFTARROW commands. If the
> number specified is zero, it sets the default number of positions to
> one half of the screen width. Alternately, the number may be specified
> as a fraction of the width of the screen, starting with a decimal
> point: .5 is half of the screen width, .3 is three tenths of the
> screen width, and so on. If the number is specified as a fraction, the
> actual number of scroll positions is recalculated if the terminal
> window is resized, so that the actual scroll remains at the specified
> fraction of the screen width.

The semicolon `:` at the bottom is the `less` command prompt, you can press `h` for help. As [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) mentioned at the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394237/arrow-keys-and-less#comment2412411_1394237) when you press `s`, the prompt `log file:` asks you for a name of a file where the input of the `less` command will be stored for later use - in the current case it is the output of `dir`.